# Creating a jbpm+spring ws

Tags: maven, spring-ws, jbpm

I'm trying to create a contract first spring web service using maven which is supposed to start a jbpm process by its id. I managed to create a simple spring ws using maven but i don't know how to relate it to my jbpm workflow, some guidance will be really appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a web service already working now you only need to setup jbpm inside your project so you can start processes just calling the APIs.
Take a look at this blog post for more information about jBPM6 and Spring:

http://mswiderski.blogspot.co.uk/2014/01/jbpm-6-with-spring.html